# why does "Integer [ ] x = (Integer [ ]) new Object[100]; " compile?

Tags: java, compilation

I compile:

```
Integer [ ] x = (Integer [ ]) new Object[100];
```

it succeeds.
and I don't know Why?

Comment: Because you lied to the compiler.

Comment: Casting is a convenience Java has given you to make the Java compiler trust you. So, it compiles but you are trying to abuse the convenience given to you. Remember [Karma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karma) 

Comment: Note that casting a literal expression happens at compile time: `int i = (int)(1.0+2.0);`  This is different than casting a reference type as the OP has.  So the OP might be asking why the reference type is different than the literal type.

Answer (score 8):

It *compiles*. But it does not *run*. Try it - shove that in a `main` method and execute it. You'll get a ClassCastException.

There are a number of things going on here. Most of this is 'programming language archeology' - none of it makes sense and none of it is particularly consistent. If your aim is to learn the language better, there's a very simple rule you should apply to your java programming:

1. Do not use arrays. At all. For anything. Except perhaps arrays of primitive types (`int[]`, `long[]`, etcetera) for performance reasons. There is no point to them. They aren't faster than lists and have all sorts of wonky downsides. Including effectively broken equals and hashCode and toString implementations (in that they do unexpected things; the spec properly explains these things, but an API that does what the spec says it does, but the spec says bizarro unexpected things, well, I'll let the reader come up with a term for it. I trust it won't be a particularly nice term), they are this useless amalgamation of immutable-ish (they can neither grow nor shrink) but not actually immutable (you can set values), and more.
2. When casting arrays, assume that the compiler has no idea and you'll have to rely on runtime exceptions. Really, once you've reached this level (You're casting arrays), you need to back up and fix whatever got you into that mess.

There is really not much point in going any further if your aim is to be a good java coder.

But, hey, you asked - so, let's put on our brown hat, grab a whip, play the Indiana Jones themesong, and go spelunkin' into the depths of java's distant past!

### Covariance, Contravariance, Invariance.

We need to cover the key problem first. An answer has already been posted by somebody who does not understand type systems, so, that's anecdotal proof this needs to be explained first.

Java's type system is itself 'covariant'. That means: Any type is a fine substitution for any of its supertypes. If you have a method that requires that you pass it a `Number` parameter, you can pass an expression of type `Integer`, no problem.

However, once you move up to listy things (be it generics, or arrays) **this does not work**. They should be **invariant** - Only the exact type required will do and no other type can substitute.

That's because you can actually both **write** *and* **read** from listy things and therein lies the problem. Here's a trivial example:

```
Integer i = 5;
Number n = i; // this is fine.

Integer[] is = new Integer[10];
Number[] ns = is; // fine, too? right? Maybe?
ns[0] = 5.5; // ... a double
Integer firstElement = is[0]; // BOOM!
```

That last line shows the problem. Because basic java types are covariant and will remain so, the `ns[0] = 5.5` line has to compile - I'm assigning a Double to a place that requires a Number. Nevertheless this leads to a problem on the last line.

**Generics gets this right**. The generics equivalent is this:

```
List<Integer> is = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> ns = is; // This does not compile!
```

And gives you the tools you need to make nice APIs; you can ask for covariance (`List<? extends Number>`, where a `List<Integer>` *is* acceptable, but the compiler prevents you from writing to this list to ensure the 'whoops there is a double in my list of integers' problem cannot occur), and even contravariance (`List<? super Integer>`, where you can pass a `List<Integer>`, or `List<Number>`, or a `List<Object>`. You can write to it (any integer - which works fine regardless of which of those 3 kinds of lists is actually passed in), but the compiler prevents you from reading. Or rather, returns `Object`, given that List in general guarantees that whatever it stores, it's at least Object).

Here's a good tip: When you read `List<? extends Number>` you may be translating that: "A list, containing things whose type is Number or subtypes of Number - you know, things whose type is.. something, that extends Number". **That is wrong**. You're supposed to read it as: "A list, limited to contain some type that *I simply do not know here* (see the question mark? That means 'don't know'). All I know is: That restriction is Number or some subtype there of. It could be a list that is only supposed to store integers. Could be Doubles. Could be any Number. No idea. Everything I do with this list must be valid regardless of whether that's a `List<Number>` or a `List<Integer>` or a `List<Double>` or any other `List<X>` where X is a subtype of Number. *It has to work for **ALL** of them or it is not valid java and the compiler will refuse it*. Hence why `list.add()` doesn't work here - there is no value that is both Double and Integer and Number and SomeSubTypeOfNumberYouHaventEvenWrittenYet. Well, except the literal `null` which indeed you can actually pass, the only way to call `add` at all.

**Arrays get this totally wrong**.

Why? Well, generics is really complicated. The notion that you need 4 different types that all are `List<Number>` adjacent but subtly different is already quite complex:

- `List` (raw/legacy type. Perhaps if java had had generics from v1.0 this would not be needed).
- `List<Number>`
- `List<? extends Number>`
- `List<? super Number>`

and java was trying to 'keep things simple' so didn't add this. Generics didn't show up until java 1.5, over a decade later.

In some ways the designers of java were apparently (it's been a looong time, I haven't asked them) also not aware that the component type of a listy thing just cannot be covariant. Or, more likely, sometimes you want to write code that operates on arbitrary arrays and the language designers decided to just let the compiler get out of the way, turn java into more or less a dynamically typed (i.e. the compiler doesn't help you) situation where only the runtime exists to prevent problems from occurring.

Hence, you can do this stuff:

```
Object is = new Integer[10];
Number[] numbers = (Number[]) is;
is[0] = 5.5;
```

That code compiles, but when you run it.. the second line works, but the third line doesn't - fails with an ArrayStoreException. That's because arrays do know what their component type is, and thus the `is[0] =..` assignment does check: Hey, what's the *actual* component type of the array object that the `is` variable is pointing at? Oh it's `Integer[]`.. hmm, then, ArrayStoreException. It's a variant of ClassCastException in that sense.

Similarly, you can actually cast Object arrays to whatever array type you want, but the system is designed so that *storing* things into arrays might fail with an ArrayStoreException, but *reading* them never will. Because it's easier to reason about code when you know certain things aren't possible. Such as non-integers being in your `Integer[]` array.

To ensure that rule, when you cast an array, the runtime checks and won't let you if it means read operations could fail. Hence why arrays are covariant-ish:

```
Object xs = new Integer[100];
Number[] ns = (Number[]) xs; // allowed
xs = new Number[100];
Integer[] is = (Integer[]) xs; // not allowed
```

Where 'not allowed' means: Usually compiles fine, but at runtime results in a `ClassCastException`.

The only reason it works that way is that the 'allowed' line is still broken (in that you'd expect an array of type `Number[]` to allow you to write any Number to it, whereas here this one doesn't and will fail with an ArrayStoreEx unless it's an Integer), but allowed because it can't break when *reading* from it (whatever is in that array, it's at least a Number. Because all Integers are Numbers and the only thing that array can store is Integer objects). Whereas the second is not allowed, because if it had been allowed, **reading from it could cause problems**. `ArrayStoreException` exists; `ArrayReadException` does not.

Why was the choice made this way? At some point we've arrived at a dead end. The answer to *that* is: "Because the spec says so" and if you want to know why *that* is the case, the answer is: "Because the designers at the time wanted it that way". Any further 'but.. why?' questions should be directed directly at James Gosling and co.

Comment: 1/5th through this answer and I already could  tell who the author was. Contravariance/Covariance/Invariance are key topics that are not easy to understand.  Well stated, and from all of us, thanks for well educating us.  1+

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the OP's question.  Why does that line compile?  The compiler will evaluate `int i = 1.0 + 2.0;` at compile time and throw an error.  But I'm pretty sure both the cast `(Integer[])` and the `new` keyword are never evaluated by the compiler like a literal is.  (But I didn't double check that.)  So there is no choice: both `new` and the cast are only evaluated at runtime.

Comment: I guess in other words I'm interpreting the OP's question as asking "The type Object[] is right there, the cast (Integer[]) is right there, why can't the compiler evaluate that and spot the error immediately?"  (Edit: but `int i = (int)(1.0+2.0);` is evaluated at compile time, so I guess casting references only happens at runtime, primitives can be evaluated at compile time; possibly this is also a source of confusion.)

Comment: The problem will be with `ns[0] = 5.5; // ... a double`, not with `Integer firstElement = is[0]; // BOOM!`.

Comment: Thanks for your time in answer me. I think, whatever, that JAVA compiler must detect the bug a compilation time, because is a NEW instruction and not a CAST assignment from an Objecjt variable. Thanks thanks

Comment: @markspace The last line of the answer explains it: It's a one-word explanation: "Because". Spec says so. Doing it right is very complicated (see middle of answer: Co/Contra/Invariance), presumably java v1.0 design threw in the towel to try to make sense of it at compile time.

Comment: In the ArrayList<AnyType> implementation, JAVA use arrays as a base type....

Comment: I don't understand what do you say in statement: "Hence why list.add() doesn't work here - there is no value that is both Double and Integer and Number and SomeSubTypeOfNumberYouHaventEvenWrittenYet." What is list ?

Comment: @Oscar Given a `List<? extends WhateverYouWant> list`, you can't call `.add()` on that list. Except, literally, `list.add(null);`. Given that `List<?>` is short for `List<? extends Object>`, you can't call `.add()` on that either.

Comment: e.g.: `List<? extends Number> listOfNumbers = ...; Number n = something; listOfNumbers.add(n);` - this does not compile. You can't `.add()` anything to this list.